# Running Controller in Angular and phpStorm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phpstorm, ng-controller, ng-app

I'm new to angular and I'm learnign it using phpStorm tool. 
It looks like I've done everything right, but I still can't get the right result when I execute the following html and Javascript codes, I did lots of researches on this and made sure that I followed the solutions provided without getting a step ahead:

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" >
<head >
    <title>Ang Tut</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Groups</h1>

<div  ng-controller="GroupController">

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="group in groups" ng-model="group.group_name">
            {{group.group_name}}
        </li>
    </ul>


</div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>


</html>
```

and my app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    app.controller("GroupController", function($scope){
        $scope.groups= [
            {"id":"144","group_name":"new grouppp"},
            {"id":"303","group_name":"Combination group"},
            {"id":"323","group_name":"pcb"}
        ]

    });
```

Comment: What does your browser's console say?

Comment: Why do you have a ng-model on `li` elements?

Comment: It's working fine. There's nothing wrong with it https://jsfiddle.net/px41hwe7/

Comment: @sp00m Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error

Comment: @nanndoj i tried to remove it , it is not the one making the problem. 
I know it works in jsfiddle but why not when working locally??? what does this error supposed to mean inside console : Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the js file, so to include "function()" at the beginning of it, and also "()" at the end line. That solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Same code is working, angular.min.js may not included properly, access your index.html file using http://  instead of file://

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

    app.controller("GroupController", function($scope){
        $scope.groups= [
            {"id":"144","group_name":"new grouppp"},
            {"id":"303","group_name":"Combination group"},
            {"id":"323","group_name":"pcb"}
        ]

    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" >
<head >
    <title>Ang Tut</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Groups</h1>

<div  ng-controller="GroupController">

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="group in groups" ng-model="group.group_name">
            {{group.group_name}}
        </li>
    </ul>


</div>

</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


</html>
```

Comment: how would you know it's a problem of  script include

Comment: you can see that angular.min.js is included, my code works fine here and also jsfiddle but it is not the same when I work locally

Comment: what does mean by error he is talking about in his console

Comment: @SamJoni how are you trying to access your file, using file://yourfile.html or http://yourfile.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include `ngRoute` in your project.

`<script src="angular-route.js">` You can get this file [**here**](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js).

And in your `app.js`

`var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);`

And it will start working correctly.

Now, the reason this works in jsFiddle but not locally.

That is because if you look at left pane in jsFiddle under `Frameworks & Extensions`, you will find the selected option to be `no wrap - in <body>`

Which means that the code you write in javascript block of js fiddle will be placed inside the body tag the the generated html and therefore, you don't need `ngRoute`.

But while running locally, I see you have your module initialization in different file viz. `app.js` that is where `ngRoute` comes into picture.

In older versions of angular ngRoute was included in angular itself. But in latest versions (not sure from which versions) the `ngRoute` module is provided separately.